# Знак после глагола в повелительном наклонении

Tags: пунктуация

Возможна ли вообще точка в предложении, начинающемся с глагола в повелительном наклонении, то есть представляющем собой обращение с просьбой что-то сделать?

Comment: Закройте, пожалуйста, окно. Можно и без "пожалуйста". Почему бы и не поставить точку?

Comment: Было бы что-то конкретное... Оно есть?

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: Знак, о котором спрашиваете, ставится в конце, а не после.

Comment: "После" ведь не обязательно означает "сразу после", а так, как Вы изменили, вообще получился непонятный смысл. Что это за знак повелительного наклонения такой?))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А хороший вопрос, однако.
Только его чуть по-другому надо сформулировать.
Есть ли предложения подобного типа ("побудительные"), где обязательно нужна точка, восклицательный противоречил бы каким-то правилам, помимо авторской воли?
Боюсь, что таких предложений нет.

Но, видимо, справедливо и обратное. Любое предложение с восклицательным знаком (скорее всего не только побудительное) можно произнести с интонацией, требующей точки. Т. е. знак этот больше для блезиру изобретен был, для акцентов. О чем нам поведал, конечно же, Антон Павлович.

> «В бумагах они ставятся, когда... тово... этого... как его? Гм!..
>   В самом деле, когда же их в бумагах ставят? Постой... дай бог память...
>   Гм!..»
>   Перекладин открыл глаза и повернулся на другой бок. Но не успел
>   он вновь закрыть глаза, как на темном фоне опять появились
>   восклицательные знаки.
>   «Чёрт их возьми... Когда же их ставить нужно? — подумал он, стараясь
>   выгнать из своего воображения непрошенных гостей. — Неужели забыл? Или
>   забыл, или же... никогда их не ставил...»
>   Перекладин стал припоминать содержание всех бумаг, которые он написал
>   за сорок лет своего служения; но как он ни думал, как ни морщил лоб, в
>   своем прошлом он не нашел ни одного восклицательного знака.
>   «Что за оказия! Сорок лет писал и ни разу восклицательного знака не
>   поставил... Гм!.. Но когда же он, чёрт длинный, ставится?»

("Восклицательный знак").

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus!

Answer (score 5):

А почему нет? Побудительные предложения бывают восклицательные и невосклицательные. Невосклицательное предложение - это предложение, содержащее приказ или просьбу, но произнесённое со спокойной интонацией. Например: *Принеси мне кофе. Расскажи сказку. Закрой тетрадь. Подточи карандаш. Ешь спокойно. Не садись на пенек, не ешь пирожок.*

Comment: Спасибо большое, Людмила!